# Why RefreshToken received form azure active directory is not in JWT format

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I need to understand why refresh token issued by AAD is not in JWT format( i used Auth Code grant type for generation of refresh token). It looks something like as follows 0.ATYAoWHs1YRqUk-OAYpDkwKjaYAEJhrbDpBNmWw7q0NZVas2APk....(rest of the token).

Also if we can get this refresh token in JWT format then how can we do that.

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

It isn't in JWT format because it does not need to be.
A refresh token is data that you send to the identity provider to get new access tokens.
It should not have any other meaning for your application.
Store it securely and send it to AAD when you need new tokens.
Then take the new refresh token you get in the response and overwrite your previous refresh token with that.

The OAuth 2 RFC also talks about it https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-10:

> A refresh token is a string representing the authorization granted to the client by the resource owner. **The string is usually opaque to the client.** The token denotes an identifier used to retrieve the authorization information. Unlike access tokens, refresh tokens are intended for use only with authorization servers and are never sent to resource servers.

Comment: hi juunas, thanks for your response. So it seems that we can not validate RefreshToken by any mean. Also one other thing which is bothering me can we stop refreshToken to get refreshed after every call on /token endpoint for refreshing access token, if yes, then how?

Comment: No, you cannot validate the refresh token. And no, you cannot stop it from being refreshed. It's a feature that you get a new one. The old refresh token will still work though. They just expire after some amount of time has passed (maybe 14 days?), that's why it is good to overwrite the existing refresh token you have for that user.